# Issue with a button that creates inputs in a form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I want to make a button that adds email inputs to a form "add another email" with a function trigged when clicking on the button, but nothing happens when I click on that button, but I don't have any errors.
There might be missing an element.

```
export class Invites extends Component {
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.nextStep();
  };

  render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
    // ==========================================
    const addEmailForm = () => {
      return (
        <li>
          <input
            class="form-input"
            type="email"
            placeholder="nom@exemple.com"
            name="invites"
            defaultValue={values.invites}
            onChange={handleChange("invites")}
            required
          />
        </li>
      );
    };
    // ==========================================
    return (
      <div class="page">
        <h2 class="box-title">Qui sont les eleves de cette classe ?</h2>
        <p>Vous pourrez toujours en ajouter par la suite</p>
        <form onSubmit={this.continue}>
          <div class="content">
            <input
              class="form-input"
              type="email"
              placeholder="nom@exemple.com"
              name="invites"
              defaultValue={values.invites}
              onChange={handleChange("invites")}
              required
            />
            <div class="add-invite">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="text-icon" src={require("../../plusIcon.png")} />
                Ajouter une autre personne
              </a> 
            </div>
          </div>

          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Ajouter des élèves"
            class="submit-button"
          />
        </form>
        <div class="link-invite">
          <ol>{addEmailForm}</ol>
          <a
            href="#"
            onClick={() => {
              this.addEmailForm();
            }}
          >
            <img class="text-icon" src={require("../../linkIcon.png")} />
            Obtenir un lien d’invitation à partager
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Invites;
```

Thanks for your help. I don't have much experience with Reactjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, what you want to do is display a list of email input dynamically, based on the number of times the user pressed the "Ajouter une autre personne" button or, from the user viewpoint, the number of students email he wants to input.

So you need a way to keep track of how many inputs you want to display. You also want the button "Ajouter une autre personne" to somehow tell your app that it needs to display one more email.

Luckily with React those are two easy things to do. You only need to use state and to create a sort of handleClick function that updates the state.

I created a very basic version of what you want to achieve using CodeSandBox that you can find here : [Form with dynamically generated email input list in React](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-http-5dc6v?fontsize=14)
Note: I am using the useState hook instead of Class, this can be done with class too though.

My very first step was to break your code down into different React components. The form is now handled by InviteForm, the email input has been moved into its own InviteInput componen and the same goes for the AddInviteButton.

Here is how you keep track on how many invites you need to show inside InviteForm:

```
  const [nbInvites, setNbInvites] = useState(1);
  const onAddInviteClick = () => {
    setNbInvites(nbInvites + 1);
  };
```

Here is how you tell React how many needs to be rendered, still in InviteForm:

```
  let inviteList = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nbInvites; i++) {
    inviteList.push(<InviteInput key={i} />);
  }
```

And then inside the return of InviteForm, this will display all the  elements

```
<form>{inviteList}</form>
```

Now we only need the button that increments the nbInvites state to tell React to show one more.

```
<AddInviteButton onClick={onAddInviteClick} />
```

If any of the above is confusing to you, I would highly recommend spending some time following the really great [React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). You will be up to speed with React's most basic concepts in no time. I hope this helped you.